# How to use CPack from CMake in bitbake

Tags: cmake, debian, bitbake, openembedded, cpack

How is it possible to override bitbakes regular internal packaging function (`do_package`) and use CPack? So a normal CMake build looks like this:

```
cmake ../src
cmake --build ../src
cmake --build ../src --target install
```

So bitbake correctly handles all of this assuming I use the `install` command inside `CMakeLists.txt` and construct my recipes correctly. So building on that, I would like to use CMake's deb package generator to build my packages. Normally this would look something like this in a CMake build to generate the `.deb` packages after the above:

```
make package
```

or

```
cmake --build ../src/ --target package
```

I was hoping I didn't have to write a pile of custom functions.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes.  You'd have to reimplement do_package to call cmake and move the files into the right places.

Realistically, why?  Packaging is mostly trivial.

Comment: In my case, because not everyone uses bitbake to build so I'd like packaging to be as similar as possible in all situations. Similarly I'd like all aspects of my build to be a similar as possible in the different scenarios -- even though obviously I won't be able to make it 100%.

Comment: This is a significant problem for me, too. There are always devs who don't know Bitbake, but need to generate a package for testing their changes. Telling these people to use Bitbake is a non-starter—they simply won't go to all that trouble when they have no other reason to even know what Bitbake is. So I'm compelled to provide a `make package` target in our CMake builds to support them. And to avoid having *two* sets of packaging instructions (in Bitbake, and in CMake), I have to override `do_package()` to delegate to CMake. It's kind of a PITA, but I haven't found a better way yet...

Comment: I'm not even going to bother for the time being. Its not an OSS project so whatever. I'm also really disappointed we're using bitbake, it's incredibly overengineered. I can't help but shake the feeling that with the time we spent trying to grok bitbake we could've used buildroot, written custom code to overcome any of its shortcomings and had time left over.